# Parsing Watir Results

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm using `Watir` for getting data from published items, 12 on a single page. Structured as presented below, I am expecting 12 items to show up, much like how `Nokogiri` parses results.  I am using the :css way of obtaining it, or the direct **browser.div**, but the result isn't what I'm expecting.

How is this different than the way `Nokogiri` grabs elements?  I'm assuming `Watir` accomplishes this in the same way.  I then need to iterate through these items to get their data.  I'm searching on the class **itemContainer**, which wraps around all 12 products on the page.

How can I get that array of divs?

```
## HTML
<div data-jplist-item="" class="itemSpace">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <a href="/en/Products/All/Tipless Chine" target="_blank" title="Click here to learn more about this product">
    <div class="name itemName">Alpha<span style="display:none;">boat part, DELTAUPDATE</span></div>
    <div class="saleDiscount" style="display:none;">25.575</div>
    <div class="itemNo" style="display:none;">1711</div>
    <div class="saleNote">SALE</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-jplist-item="" class="itemSpace">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <a href="/en/Products/All/Something" target="_blank" title="Click here to learn more about this product">
    <div class="name itemName">Bravo<span style="display:none;">boat part</span></div>
    <div class="saleDiscount" style="display:none;">300</div>
    <div class="itemNo" style="display:none;">584</div>
    <div class="saleNote">SALE</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-jplist-item="" class="itemSpace">
  <div class="itemContainer">
    <a href="/en/Products/All/Something Else" target="_blank" title="Click here to learn more about this product">
    <div class="name itemName">Charlie<span style="display:none;">boat part</span></div>
    <div class="saleDiscount" style="display:none;">600</div>
    <div class="itemNo" style="display:none;">413</div>
    <div class="saleNote">SALE</div></a>
  </div>
</div>

## code
##### a is the browser
item = a.div(class: "itemContainer")
ap item.inspect
puts item.class 


## result
"#<Watir::Div: located: false; {:class=>\"itemSpace\", :tag_name=>\"div\"}>"
Watir::Div
```

Comment: Show what is the expected output

Comment: An array of some sort, like I said in the description.

Comment: If you want more Nokogiri-like experience, I would recommend you to try Ferrum

Comment: I’m currently parsing using `Nokigiri` for clarity.  I use `Ferrum` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear about your question. But I have printed link title and first division text here.

```
b.divs(class: 'itemContainer').each do |div|
  p div.a.title
  p div.a.div.text
end
```

Output

```
"Click here to learn more about this product"
"Alpha"
"Click here to learn more about this product"
"Bravo"
"Click here to learn more about this product"
"Charlie"
```

Comment: OK that provides some guidance.  Their documentation on the site doesn't use **.divs** at all, just **.div** for the first instance.  Works great.  Thank you.